# CTTypesetter crashing on weird Unicode characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-text

I'm using CTTypesetter to layout messages read in from JSON from a server. However, on certain particular messages it crashes, namely those with unusual Unicode characters like the one below.

```
CFAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, @"❝Ｗｅ  ｍｕｓｔ  ｌｅａｒｎ  ｔｏ  ｌｉｖｅ  ｔｏｇｅｔｈｅｒ  ａｓ  ｂｒｏｔｈｅｒｓ  ｏｒ  ｐｅｒｉｓｈ  ｔｏｇｅｔｈｅｒ  ａｓ  ｆｏｏｌｓ❞ ~Martin Luther King Jr. #HappyMLKDay", nil);
CTTypesetterRef typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
```

That crashes with the below stack trace.

```
#0  0x33a4684e in TBaseFont::CopyCharacterSet() const ()
#1  0x33a2c0d4 in CompareCharSet(__CFCharacterSet const*, TBaseFont const*) ()
#2  0x33a2f03e in TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequestFromArray(__CFArray const*, __CFDictionary const*, long (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long, bool) const ()
#3  0x33a2ead0 in TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, long (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long) const ()
#4  0x33a2e624 in TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, long (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long) const ()
#5  0x33a2e532 in TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptor(CGFont*, unsigned short const*, long) const ()
#6  0x33a2e79c in TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptor(CGFont*, __CFString const*, CFRange) const ()
#7  0x33a27c78 in TFontCascade::CreateSystemWideFallback(__CTFont const*, __CFString const*, CFRange) const ()
#8  0x33a27b28 in TFontCascade::CreateFallback(__CTFont const*, __CFString const*, CFRange) const ()
#9  0x33a185ec in TGlyphEncoder::AppendUnmappedCharRun(CTRun*, CFRange, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const&, bool) ()
#10 0x33a184b8 in TGlyphEncoder::RunUnicodeEncoderRecursively(CTRun*, adopted_t const&, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const*, bool) ()
#11 0x33a186e4 in TGlyphEncoder::AppendUnmappedCharRun(CTRun*, CFRange, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const&, bool) ()
#12 0x33a184b8 in TGlyphEncoder::RunUnicodeEncoderRecursively(CTRun*, adopted_t const&, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const*, bool) ()
#13 0x33a1824c in TGlyphEncoder::RunUnicodeEncoder(CTRun*, adopted_t const&, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const*) ()
#14 0x33a07a1a in TGlyphEncoder::EncodeChars(CFRange, TAttributes const&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphEncoder::Fallbacks) ()
#15 0x33a0665c in TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) ()
#16 0x33a064a4 in TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) ()
#17 0x33a06418 in TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) ()
#18 0x33a1e78c in CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString ()
```

I created an empty project to try and reproduce the crash, however in this environment it works fine.

The documentation has this to say:

> Multicore Considerations: All individual functions in Core Text are
>   thread safe. Font objects (CTFont, CTFontDescriptor, and associated
>   objects) can be used by simultaneously by multiple operations, work
>   queues, or threads. However, the layout objects (CTTypesetter,
>   CTFramesetter, CTRun, CTLine, CTFrame, and associated objects) should
>   be used in a single operation, work queue, or thread.

To this end I've taken out all kind of threading, namely a few `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ...)`, in an attempt to resolve this. I don't know what else I can try to solve it besides gutting what is a >20 KSLOC project.

It only crashes the actual iPad (all 3 models tested with both 5.0 and 5.1), not the simulator.

What can I try to solve this? I'm about to resort to embedding modified versions of Helvetica with as many fallback fonts merged into them as possible, but that's a far from optimal solution.

Any input at all would be incredibly appreciated, as you can see this has been driving me insane since January!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

I was referencing 43 fonts in my info.plist. All were valid, all were otf's or ttf's in my resource bundle. I just removed a few and it started working.

Damn Apple bug.

Comment: Better than cursing other people's bugs, produce the minimum reproducible case and [report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) it, so that it gets fixed.